# How to read XML with muiltiple elements of the same name with outoverwriting using Jackson?

Tags: java, xml, jackson

XML:

```
<event>
    <datum key="id" value="1"/>
    <datum key="pk" value="449272"/>
    <datum key="start_time" value="2016-10-01T18:05:00-0700"/>
</event>
```

Java Code:

```
new XmlMapper().readValue(StreamUtils.copyToString(json, Charsets.UTF_8), new TypeReference<List<Object>>() {});
```

In the returning list only the last datum appears. It appears that each datum overwrites the others. Is there a way to configure the `XmlMapper` so that rather than getting:

```
key -> "id"
value -> "1"
```

I get:

```
"id" -> "1"
```

Comment: Do you really need `jackson` for this ? I think [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html)  would be sufficient.

Comment: @svasa How would I do this a JAXB? I know the is an `@XmlAttribute`. Is there an `@XmlAttributeValue`